# WiX plugin installer needs to reference primary installation

Tags: plugins, installation, wix, file-type

I have created a second plugin for my primary program which allows it to open additional file extensions.  Now when creating the "Verb" element to associate the new file extension with the executable of the primary executable (installed from a different installer which I also created) I do not know how to reference said executable.

```
  <!-- Associate file type -->
  <ProgId Id='myfile' Description='My file'>
    <Extension Id='ext' ContentType='application/ext'>
      <Verb Id='open' Command='Open' TargetFile="INSERT MAGIC HERE" Argument='"%1"' />
    </Extension>
  </ProgId>
```

thanks
brian

Comment: I think you want to use the TargetProperty attribute, which should be the name of a property.  You'll need to use an AppSearch or SetProperty action to set the value of that property.

Comment: Do these installers share the same upgrade code? Maybe you should create a major upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the GUID of the Component that installed the file that is the target of the shortcut a ComponentSearch is the easiest way to get what you want. Something like:

```
<Property Id="TARGET_FILE">
  <ComponentSearch Id="FindTargetFile" Guid="{GUID-OF-TARGET-FILE-COMPONENT}" Type="file">
     <FileSearch Id="FoundTargetFile" Name="file.exe" />
  </ComponentSearch>
</Property>

<Component>
<ProgId Id='myfile' Description='My file'>
  <Extension Id='ext' ContentType='application/ext'>
    <Verb Id='open' Command='Open' TargetProperty="[TARGET_FILE]" Argument='"%1"' />
  </Extension>
</ProgId>
</Component>
```

Comment: I believe you mean TargetPropery instead of TargetFile. Am I right? I am having the same problem as Brian but I am unable to get your solution to work. How can I tell if the TARGET_FILE property is getting set correctly? The verbose logs do not say. It only says that AppSearch returns 1.

Comment: Oops, yes, typo. A verbose log file should show you the changes to every property as they happen. Just search for your Property/@Id in a verbose log file.